# Flutter Internationalisation - Chinese (Traditional) Legacy language is not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have to implement Chinese and Chinese (Traditional) Legacy language for my `flutter` app. **Other languages and Chinese language is working fine**, but Chinese (Traditional) legacy language is not working. Folder name is `l10n` and the language file names of Chinese language and Chinese (Traditional) legacy languages are `app_zh.arb` and `app_zh_Hant.arb` respectively. The auto generated files for the language files are fine. Chinese and Chinese (Traditional) legacy auto generated files are attached in bellow,

```
import 'app_localizations.dart';


/// The translations for Chinese (`zh`).
class AppLocalizationsZh extends AppLocalizations {
  AppLocalizationsZh([String locale = 'zh']) : super(locale);


  @override
  String get language => '中国人';


  @override
  String get username => '用户名';


  @override
  String get password => '密码';


  @override
  String get signin => '登录';
}


/// The translations for Chinese, using the Han script (`zh_Hant`).
class AppLocalizationsZhHant extends AppLocalizationsZh {
  AppLocalizationsZhHant(): super('zh_Hant');


  @override
  String get language => '中國（傳統）遺產';


  @override
  String get username => '用戶名';


  @override
  String get password => '密碼';


  @override
  String get signin => '登錄';
}
```

When It's calling in the main file, I have used the following code,

```
localizationsDelegates: const [
   AppLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
],
supportedLocales: L10n.all,
locale: const Locale('zh'),
```

I have tried the below methods to call Chinese(Traditional) Legacy language but it's not worked.

```
// locale: const Locale('zh_Hant'),
// locale: const Locale('zh' , 'Hant'), // with scriptcode
```

Also, tried language code as `zh-CHT`.
**How do I implement Chinese (Traditional) Legacy language.?**